# How can I perform a keyword search within YouTube comments using python?

Tags: python, youtube, comments, sentiment-analysis, keyword-search

I want to extract comments from youtube videos to apply sentiment analysis but I want to apply the analyse only to the relevant with the video content to avoid spam and ads, so is there any solution to search for keywords in the comments ??

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0):

Possible you can use beautiful soup to extract comment than you can use re (regular expression) module to search on the basis of keywords pattern.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html